# Scripting a sophisticated RTS AI with Lua

Tags: ai, scripting, lua

I'm planning to develop a somewhat [sophisticated RTS AI](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57972/application-of-game-trees-in-ai) (eg see [BWAPI](http://code.google.com/p/bwapi/wiki/Academics)).  have experience programming, but none in game development, so it seems easiest to start by scripting the AI of an existing game I've played, Warhammer 40k: Dawn of War (2004). As far as I can tell, the game AI is scripted with some variant of Lua (by the file extension .ai or .scar). The online documentation is sparse and the [community isn't active](http://forums.relicnews.com/forumdisplay.php?231-DoW-Modding-Tutorials-and-How-Tos) anymore.

I'd like to get some idea of the difficulty of this undertaking. Is it practical with a scripting language like Lua to develop a RTS AI that includes FSMs, decision trees, case-based reasoning, and transposition tables?

If someone has any experience scripting Dawn of War, that would also help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LUA would work fine for programming an AI.

Here is a basic article over making a FSM in LUA

http://lua-users.org/wiki/FiniteStateMachine

Here is a basic set of classes to make a desicion tree in LUA

http://gamecode4.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Assets/Scripts/DecisionTreeBrain.lua

LUA overall is an extremely powerful language. Any scripting language would have the ability to program an AI.